# How to process POST data from Golang into PHP using Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, go

I am trying to call a PHP post api in Golang using HTTP package with some post values. After sending these parameters from Golang I am trying to get it into PHP $_POST array in Wordpress. But I am not able to access any index of $_POST array in PHP code.

Here is my code:

```
func SaveProviderInGlobalDb(providerId int, providerEmail string, businessName string) (*http.Response, error){
    postValues := url.Values{}
    providerIdString := strconv.Itoa(providerId)
    postValues.Add("provider_id", providerIdString)
    postValues.Add("provider_email", providerEmail)
    postValues.Add("business_name", businessName)
    response, err := http.PostForm("http://localhost/provider.php", postValues)
    return response, err
}
```

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0){
    if(isset($_POST["business_name"]) && $_POST["business_name"] != ''){
        $providersCount = GetProviderCount($_POST["business_name"], $_POST["provider_email"]);
        if($providersCount > 0) {
            $response["response"] = "This provider is already registered for ".$_POST["business_name"];
            $response["code"] = 400;
        }else{
            $result = SaveProvider($_POST);
            if($result){
                $response["response"] = "Provider saved successfully.";
                $response["code"] = 200;
            }else{
                $response["response"] = "Error while saving provider.";
                $response["code"] = 400;
            }
        }
    }else {
        $response["response"] = "No merchant found.";
        $response["code"] = 400;    
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

In the above PHP code I am not able to check if "business_name" is set in $_POST or not. Due to this, It always gives me error message that "No merchant found."

**EDITED**

```
Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundaryGPuoAolbEsWBZnVh
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => \"provider_email\"

john_doe_1234@example.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryGPuoAolbEsWBZnVh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"provider_id\"

54
------WebKitFormBoundaryGPuoAolbEsWBZnVh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"business_name\"

testkom1
------WebKitFormBoundaryGPuoAolbEsWBZnVh--

)
```

It is the response which I am getting after printing $_POST.

Can anyone tell me how do I solve this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest check  what POST data ur getting $_POST in using var_dump($_POST)  or print_r($_POST) so that u can check what went wrong

Comment: @MaheshHegde I have edited the question with $_POST response. I had already done this.

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition statement:

```
if(isset($_POST["business_name"]) && $_POST["business_name"] != '')
```

to:

```
if(!empty($_POST["business_name"]))
```

I hope it could do the job.

Comment: No, it did not solve the problem. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have accidentally passed x-WWW-form-urlencoded headers in post request. Due to this it was generating output like above. When I removed this header, It worked fine.

Thanks!